# How can I use row index values as column for dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose, melt

So, I collected data from 21 participants with 16 EEG channels and I extracted the Gamma band. My current dataframe looks like this ([336 rows x 2 columns]):

| Channels | Gamma |
| --- | --- |
| Fp1 | 0.345908 |
| Fp2 | 0.121232 |
| F3 | 0.213212 |
| ..... | .... |

Now I want to transpose it in such a way, that I have the gamma values for each channel in one column. Like this:

| Fp1 | Fp2 | F3 | .... | Oz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.067005 | 0.345908 | 0.207540 | .... | 0.013512 |
| 0.137292 | 0.121232 | 0.121210 | .... | 0.121111 |
| 0.112121 | 0.213212 | 0.123443 | .... | 0.432233 |

when I just transpose the dataframe, then I get one row with all channels next to each other:

| Fp1 | Fp1 | Fp1 | .... | Oz | Oz | Oz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.067005 | 0.345908 | 0.207540 | .... | 0.013512 | 0.12123 | 0.112423 |

I looked at  pd.melt but I can't figure it out. Can someone help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you add a few lines of your existing dataframe that can be copied?

Comment: how are you reading the raw data into your dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to group by the Channels and then set these groups as columns of your new dataframe. Assuming following dataframe:

```
  Channels     Gamma
0      Fp1  0.345908
1      Fp2  0.121232
2      Fp1  0.455908
3      Fp2  0.213212
```

Then apply this code to the dataframe:

```
pd.concat(
        {k: g.reset_index(drop=True) 
            for k, g in df.groupby('Channels')['Gamma']}, axis=1)
```

and receive the following output:

```
        Fp1       Fp2
0  0.345908  0.121232
1  0.455908  0.213212
```

Comment: Glad I could help!